# Dask Using SQLAlchemy join as table for dask.dataframe.read_sql - index_col can't make both pandas and dask happy

Tags: dask, dask-distributed, dask-dataframe

I have an SQLAlchemy sqlalchemy.sql.selectable.Join object I created so that I could pull in a join of several tables into a dask dataframe.

Join def:

```py
joined = TABLE1.join(TABLE2, TABLE1.c.COL1 == TABLE2.c.COL2)
joined = joined.outerjoin(TABLE3, TABLE1.c.COL1 == TABLE3.c.COL3)
joined = joined.outerjoin(TABLE4, TABLE1.c.COL1 == TABLE4.c.COL4)
joined = joined.join(TABLE5, TABLE1.c.COL5 == TABLE5.c.COL6)
joined = joined.outerjoin(TABLE6, TABLE5.c.COL7 == TABLE6.c.COL8)
joined = joined.outerjoin(TABLE7, TABLE6.c.COL9 == TABLE7.c.COL10)
```

If I read a subset into pandas direct like this, it works:

```py
pd_df_join = pd.read_sql_query(
    join.select().limit(10000).compile(engine, compile_kwargs={'literal_binds': True}).string, engine, index_col='COL1')
```

However if I try and do the same thing with dask I hit one of two errors, either Pandas or Dask can't find the column I am referring to.
Pandas:

```py
In[15]: dd_df_join = dd.read_sql_table(join, engine_uri, index_col='SCHEMANAME_TABLE1_COL1', limits=(1,10000), npartitions=1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/akettmann/venvs/tableau-extract/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3331, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-15-d824e7a80ef7>", line 1, in <module>
    dd_df_join = dd.read_sql_table(join, engine_uri, index_col='SCHEMANAME_TABLE1_COL1', limits=(1,10000), npartitions=1)
  File "/home/akettmann/venvs/tableau-extract/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/dataframe/io/sql.py", line 137, in read_sql_table
    head = pd.read_sql(q, engine, **kwargs)
  File "/home/akettmann/venvs/tableau-extract/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 438, in read_sql
    chunksize=chunksize,
  File "/home/akettmann/venvs/tableau-extract/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1237, in read_query
    parse_dates=parse_dates,
  File "/home/akettmann/venvs/tableau-extract/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 129, in _wrap_result
    frame.set_index(index_col, inplace=True)
  File "/home/akettmann/venvs/tableau-extract/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 4303, in set_index
    raise KeyError(f"None of {missing} are in the columns")
KeyError: "None of ['SCHEMANAME_TABLE1_COL1'] are in the columns"
```

Dask:

```py
In[16]: dd_df_join2 = dd.read_sql_table(join, engine_uri, index_col='COL1', limits=(1,10000), npartitions=1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/akettmann/venvs/tableau-extract/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3331, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-16-b639079b01cd>", line 1, in <module>
    dd_df_join2 = dd.read_sql_table(join, engine_uri, index_col='COL1', limits=(1,10000), npartitions=1)
  File "/home/akettmann/venvs/tableau-extract/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/dataframe/io/sql.py", line 110, in read_sql_table
    index = table.columns[index_col] if isinstance(index_col, str) else index_col
  File "/home/akettmann/venvs/tableau-extract/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_collections.py", line 194, in __getitem__
    return self._data[key]
KeyError: 'COL1'
```

I am not sure if there is a way around this, or if I am doing something in a misguided way. Any assistance is very appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inputs should be just the sql expression, do not compile or mix expression and strings.

In this case, it probably looks like

```
pd_df_join = dd.read_sql_table(join, engine_uri, index_col=TABLE1.c.COL1)
```

Comment: I had to change it very slightly, but at least now my issue is type conversion! hah:

```python
df = dd.read_sql_table(join, engine_uri, index_col=TABLE1.c.COL1.label('COL1'), limits=(1, 10000), npartitions=1, head_rows=1000)```

Comment: (if you really only have one partition, you may not want to use dask)

Comment: Oh, I am only using 1 partition because I am pulling a small chunk right now while I figure out how I need to get stuff to talk. The actual dataset is 10s of GBs. In your opinion would it make sense to instead of chasing type cast errors and the like to just make a frame for each table and do the join logic in dask?

Comment: No, your DB is probably very good at JOINs from several tables and may be able to optimise out some unnecessary work. Of course, you can benchmark...

Comment: I found that part of my issue was due to having a table join but also having further criteria/filters on it. Once I gave it just a bare table join, a lot of my issues went away. I just did the filtering I was going to do in SQL in Dask/Pandas instead. Works like a charm now, pulls the data much much quicker so I can get it back to pandas for final data cleaning.